# How can I match items in my array with items in my object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures

Take the following data structure

```
report = {
   fraud_ids: [2, 3, 4, 15],
}

 fraudTypes: {
      ACH: {
        fraud_category: "fraud",
        fraud_subcategory: "a",
        fraud_type_id: "4",
      },
      'Account takeover': {
        fraud_category: "misc",
        fraud_subcategory: "a",
        fraud_type_id: "2",
      },
      'Advance fee': { 
        fraud_category: "fraud",
        fraud_subcategory: "b",
        fraud_type_id: "8",
      },
      'Against Financial Institution Customer(s)': {
        fraud_category: "cyber",
        fraud_subcategory: "b",
        fraud_type_id: "15",
      },
      'Against Financial Institution(s)': {
        fraud_category: "cyber",
        fraud_subcategory: "a",
        fraud_type_id: "78",
      },
      'Alters or cancels transaction to avoid BSA recordkeeping requirement': {
        fraud_category: "structuring",
        fraud_subcategory: "a",
        fraud_type_id: "3",
      },
   }
```

I want to match the fraudTypes object with correct number in the array by fraud_type_id. And when I find a match I want to just return the key of the object.

So using the example above I would return
`['Account takeover', 'Alters or cancels transaction to avoid BSA recordkeeping requirement', 'ACH', Against Financial Institution Customer(s)']`

I wrote the following logic and to my surprise I get an array of four items that return undefined.

```
const x = report.fraud_ids.map(id => {
  Object.keys(fraudTypes).map(fraudDescription => {
    if (parseInt(fraudTypes[fraudDescription].fraud_type_id, 10) === id) {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

I expected this to return the matching four objects and then I know I have to write additional logic just to return the keys. What am I doing wrong?

Please see the [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sea-082ne3?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from the first callback, nor is `.map` the correct inner method - instead use `.find` to find the key with the matching ID.

```js
report={fraud_ids:[2,3,4,15],fraudTypes:{ACH:{fraud_category:"fraud",fraud_subcategory:"a",fraud_type_id:"4"},"Account takeover":{fraud_category:"misc",fraud_subcategory:"a",fraud_type_id:"2"},"Advance fee":{fraud_category:"fraud",fraud_subcategory:"b",fraud_type_id:"8"},"Against Financial Institution Customer(s)":{fraud_category:"cyber",fraud_subcategory:"b",fraud_type_id:"15"},"Against Financial Institution(s)":{fraud_category:"cyber",fraud_subcategory:"a",fraud_type_id:"78"},"Alters or cancels transaction to avoid BSA recordkeeping requirement":{fraud_category:"structuring",fraud_subcategory:"a",fraud_type_id:"3"}}};

const x = report.fraud_ids.map(id => (
  Object.keys(report.fraudTypes).find(fraudDescription =>
    Number(report.fraudTypes[fraudDescription].fraud_type_id) === id)
));
console.log(x);
```

Comment: When I apply this locally I still see I'm getting undefined when I log x.

Comment: And when I console.log( Number(report.fraudTypes[fraudDescription].fraud_type_id) === id)) it returns just true. I'm not getting the keys of the objects.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code in the answer exactly? Try copy-and-pasting the whole thing. Otherwise, if you're sure you're using the exact same code, since the snippet works fine using the data structure in your question, the data you're using locally must be different - can you edit the question to show your actual data structure?

Comment: The update is minor FraudTypes is not part of report, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code in the answer exactly? Make sure to return from the first callback (see the `(`), and also change the inner `.map` to `.find`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but there it goes.

```
const selectedFrauds = report.fraud_ids.map((id, index) => {
  return(
    Object.values(fraudTypes).map((fraud, idx) => {
      return id === +fraud.fraud_type_id ? fraud : "";
    })
  )
})

const cleanSelectedFrauds = selectedFrauds.map((el) => {
  return el.filter((innerEl) => {
    if(innerEl) {
      return innerEl
    }
  })
});


console.log(cleanSelectedFrauds)
```

This will return the following array:

```
[
  [
    {
      fraud_category: 'misc',
      fraud_subcategory: 'a',
      fraud_type_id: '2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      fraud_category: 'structuring',
      fraud_subcategory: 'a',
      fraud_type_id: '3'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      fraud_category: 'fraud',
      fraud_subcategory: 'a',
      fraud_type_id: '4'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      fraud_category: 'cyber',
      fraud_subcategory: 'b',
      fraud_type_id: '15'
    }
  ]
]
```